# Generic function error

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to write simple C# function with generics. Array parser for example.

```
public static int parse_array <T> ( string str, ref T[] array ) 
    where T : IConvertible<T>
{
    string[] vals=str.Split(new char[]{'','\t',',',';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    if( vals==null || vals.Length==0 )
        return 0;

    array = new T[vals.Length];

    for( int i=0; i<vals.Length; i++ )
    {
        array[i] = Convert.ChangeType ( vals[i], T );
    }

    return vals.Length; 
}
```

but I got error: The non-generic type 'System.IConvertable' cannot be used with the type argument.
What's wrong ?

Comment: FYI, C# doesn't have templates. It has "generics". They're not the same as C++ templates.

Comment: Be sure to fix your `Convert.ChangeType` line as well, it should read `array[i] = Convert.ChangeType ( vals[i], typeof(T) );` (notice the `typeof`)

Comment: Another error:  Another error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'T'. An explicit conversion exist (are you missing cast ?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your specific compiler error is that `IConvertible` is not a generic interface, your clause should be:

```
where T : IConvertible
```

not

```
where T : IConvertible<T>
```

Indeed, the compiler error is telling you you are trying to put type arguments (that is, `<T>`) on a non-generic type (that is, the interface `IConvertible`).  While some interfaces are generic or have a generic parallel, `IConvertible` isn't one of them.

Then, in addition, you'll want to use `typeof(T)` instead of `T` in your call to `ChangeType`, since `T` is a type-name and not an instance of `Type` as Chris mentions...

Comment: "Then, in addition, you'll want to use typeof(T) instead of T in your call to ChangeType, since T is a type-name and not an instance of Type as Chris mentions..."

I changed code to:

array[i] = Convert.ChangeType ( vals[i], typeof(T) );


Another error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'T'. An explicit conversion exist (are you missing cast ?)

Comment: Yes, `ChangeType()` returns `object`, not an instance of `T`, so you'll need to cast: `array[i] = (T)Convert.ChangeType(vals[i], typeof(T));`

Comment: That is, it returns `vals[i]` converted to type `T` but returned as an `object` which you must then cast to type `T` (just a type-cast, is not a conversion cast at this point).

Answer (score 2):

I see that this has already been answered, guess I was a bit slow. But i added a simpler implementation of the Array conversion.

```
public static int parse_array<T>(string str, ref T[] array) where T : IConvertible
{
    string[] vals = str.Split(new char[] { '\t', ',', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    if (vals == null || vals.Length == 0)
        return 0;

    array = Array.ConvertAll<string, T>(vals, (o) => (T)Convert.ChangeType(o, typeof(T)));

    return vals.Length;
}
```